# Understanding syntax

Tags: syntax, foxpro

Assume that I have a foxpro `.dbf` file with schema such that there is a single column called `active` that is a [Logical datatype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ht3wzswb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Then the following query is run against it:

```
select * from table.dbf where active =.T. and active
```

What does the second `active` mean in this context? And why?

Any documentation would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using logical fields in Foxpro, you can filter by the logical field using:

```
 WHERE MyField = .t.
```

or

```
 WHERE MyField
```

These have the same meaning. In your example, the second "active" means the same as the first "active". You could remove the second "Active".

Comment: Do you have any documentation for this? My testing has confirmed your answer, but I would like to have some documentation to share with my team to support/explain the code change.

Comment: Try the Logical Operators page in the VFP help. While it doesn't say it explicitly, the examples make it clear that you don't need to compare the values to .T. and .F.